# Not Getting XML data in proper formate to display in Table View in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xml-parsing

```
import UIKit
var operationViewFlag: Int!
var dataReceived: Int!

class HomeCellView: UITableViewCell
{

@IBOutlet weak var btn_tablecell_Delete: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn_tablecell_Edit: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_tablecell_Email: UILabel!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate
{
@IBOutlet weak var TableView_Mainscreen: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_MainScreen_Title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btn_Mainscreen_Insert: UIButton!

var databasepath:String!
var arrayStudInfo:NSMutableArray!



// for only xml parsing
var parser = NSXMLParser()
var posts = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()
var title1 = NSMutableString()
var date = NSMutableString()

// viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad()
{

    super.viewDidLoad()
    arrayStudInfo = NSMutableArray()        
    self.beginParsing();
    TableView_Mainscreen.reloadData()
}

//viewWillAppear
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    TableView_Mainscreen.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// TableView Methods
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    print("Number Of Row:\(posts.count)")
    return posts.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellHome") as! HomeCellView

    print("Index path - > \(posts[indexPath.row])")

    Cell.lbl_tablecell_Email.text! = String("\(posts[(indexPath.row)]["title"])")
    return Cell
}  
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
{
    element = elementName
    print("element Name : - \(elementName)")
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item")
    {
        elements = NSMutableDictionary()
        elements = [:]
        title1 = NSMutableString()
        title1 = ""
        date = NSMutableString()
        date = ""
    }
}


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
{
    print("element Name : - \(elementName)")
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item")
    {
        if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
            elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "Name")
        }
        if !date.isEqual(nil) {
            elements.setObject(date, forKey: "Level")
        }
        posts.addObject(elements)
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{
    if element.isEqualToString("Name")
    {
        title1.appendString(string)
    } else if element.isEqualToString("Level") {
        date.appendString(string)
    }
}
func beginParsing()
{
    posts = []
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/Party.xml"))!)!

    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}

func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {
    TableView_Mainscreen.reloadData()
}
}
```

I want to display the result of the xml api in proper formate. I want to display the name from it, in table view. Right now i am not getting any data from this. First of all If will get any data then and then we can think to convert or arrange in any formate , but i am not getting any thing. will anybody please help for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Oh! I didn't check your XML thoroughly enough! In fact, it has nothing to do with the parser loading the data asynchronously (I'll leave my original hint regarding `parserDidEndDocument` below, though, you might need it once you implement a refresh feature).

Turns out you simply did not use the correct names, i.e. strings for the elements. Here's the corrected code:

In `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` (note I slightly changed how to get the string, otherwise you might get an ugly prefix in it)

```
...
        let nameString = posts[(indexPath.row)]["Name"] as! String
        Cell.lbl_tablecell_Email.text = nameString
...
```

In `parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])`

```
...
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("Player")
...
```

In `parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)`

```
...
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("Player")
...
```

In `parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)` (note you seem to have a linebreak and some whitespaces in your XML, I cut that off)

```
...
    if element.isEqualToString("Name") && !(string.hasPrefix("\n"))
...
```

I assume you didn't realize those string keys that identify the elements are actually just the element's name, basically. There's a couple of small things in your code that could be optimized and/or improved (for example you don't need to initialize some `var`s, since you just re-init them elsewhere before actual usage anyways, also the naming of variables).

I tried it out with the link you provided and it works now.

*Gist of previous answer:*
Implement

```
func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {
    TableView_Mainscreen.reloadData()
}
```

so that you are guaranteed to reload the table's data after the parser is done parsing.

Comment: i have edited my code. so Now You will  get proper idea. about not getting data

Comment: If you want to I can also give you a git repo showing you the minor things with your code.

Comment: ya sure you can share the link

Comment: Thank you Very Much Dear... it works fine now. I can show the Name in Table Veiw in My project. Superb.